# Receive SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON in Webstorm but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm, ecmascript-5, jetbrains-ide

I am working on the a project and I have the following call

```
try {this.set("config", JSON.parse(dijitConfig));}
```

with dijitConfig =

```
"\r\n{\r\n    \"getStationUrl\" : \"http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/testcenterline/MapServer/exts/StationLocator/GetStation\",\t\r\n\t\"tolerance\" : 5,\r\n\t\"getStationInterval\" : 1\r\n}\n//# sourceURL=http://localhost:63342/StationLocator/Main/StationLocator%20JSAPI/Source/StationLocator%20JSAPI/js/StationLocatorConfig.js"
```

For some reason, when I run this through Chrome the app launches without error, inside of Webstorm I receive the following exception:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 180
```

Why is this JSON valid in Chrome but not Webstorm?

Note in Webstorm I have HTML5/ECMAScript 5 enabled in `Settings->Languages & Frameworks->JavaScript->Libraries`

Comment: There are only 148ish characters in the stringified version of the JSON you've shown above. Is that the object where the error is actually being thrown? (there is no position 180).

Comment: @Josh Beam my apologies, see the redacted paste

Answer (score 0):

If `dijitConfig` is a javascript object and not a string, `JSON.parse()` will fail. You can only parse strings into objects.

if you're loading this an AJAX request, the `Accept` headers may be incorrect and the server may be returning the wrong format. I've had this happen before in Firefox where AJAX requests specifically required the `Accept` header set to `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid JSON. For example, when I do this:

```
JSON.parse("\r\n{\r\n    \"getStationUrl\" : \"http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/testcenterline/MapServer/exts/StationLocator/GetStation\",\t\r\n\t\"tolerance\" : 5,\r\n\t\"getStationInterval\" : 1\r\n}\n//# sourceURL=http://localhost:63342/StationLocator/Main/StationLocator%20JSAPI/Source/StationLocator%20JSAPI/js/StationLocatorConfig.js")
```

I get: `StationLocatorConfig.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 179`.

You need to make sure your config is valid JSON. Try using a [JSON linter](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I inserted this into the Linter with the JSON.parse call, so just the raw JSON string and it reports it as valid

Comment: @Rice the string will appear to be valid because it's simply a string. If you paste the parsed object, however, you'll see it's invalid.